# Undefined references on run, SSL

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

Trying out Kemal in a VM, fresh install of Arch-Linux with gc, openssl, crystal, and shard packages. Ran through steps on Kemal guide for simple web app, but errors upon `crystal run src/test_app.cr`:

> _main.o: In function '__crystal_main':
>   /usr/lib/crystal/openssl/lib_ssl.cr:213: undefined reference to 'SSL_Library_init'

...followed by a lot of similar error messages, undefined references etc.

Am I missing a dependency?

Comment: I can run a basic crystal program without kemal, such as puts "Hello World", with no problem

Comment: Are you pissing the `pkg-config` package? You should install the `base-devel` group.

Comment: How did you install crystal?

Comment: @Shelvacu pacman -S crystal

Comment: @RX14 that was it. After installing base-devel everything was cool. Care to write as answer, so I can mark this question as answered in case someone else experiences same error?

Comment: @AaronThomas done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `base-devel` package group using `pacman -S base-devel`.

On Arch Linux, Crystal is a compiler package so it assumes you have `base-devel` installed. Without the `pkg-config` package, Crystal can't find out which version of OpenSSL you have installed and can't link to it.